# Sending BTC from two addresses that are generated in other nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, sending

**Is there a way to utilize bitcoin core that is installed in my server being as a mediator sending BTC from two addresses, which are generated in other cores?**

```
 For example,

 James has BTC address A that is generated in Bittrex Exchange.

 Sam has BTC address B that is generated in Binance Exchange.

 Bitcoin core in my server acts as a mediator helping James to trasnfer his BTC to Sam using my core.
```

It is one of the MyEtherWallet functions, so as a developer I feel curious how they transfer BTC from my BTC address to the recipient.

I will be very appreciated if anyone knows about this and guide me through.

Any references will be grateful!

Comment: I don't quite follow. Why would they need help?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What do you mean you don't quite follow? You don't understand the question itself? or you don't know why I need to know? 
I'm currently working on my personal project to develop a site similar to MyEtherWallet.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are misunderstanding how bitcoin works? address are not generated by nodes ... node only exist to validate your tx (or to prevent double spending problem) then it gets add to the mempool from there to the blockchain ... now only the miner have the power to write your tx to the blockchain they are both dependant to each other

i dont know what you mean by MyEtherWallet.... are you developing something or making payment to someone?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Basically, what I would like to implement is the function that enables users to send coins each other. 
I only tested sending my bitcoin to someone ```bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress "recipient" "amount"```after unlokcing with the command ```bitcoin-cli walletpassphrase "passphrase" "time"``` But this does not work if sender's account address are not generated within my wallet.